# DeviceFirmwareVersion, OSVersion, DeviceStatus missing in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

in my Silverlight Windows Phone 7/8 projects I always used these methods/classes to get informations about the user phone:

```
Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceFirmwareVersion;
System.Environment.OSVersion.Version;
Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName;
Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer;
```

But now in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime they are missing. Are there some alternatives? My app doesn't use networking.
Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Seems like the properties are still available in WP 8.1. Did you double check? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus_properties(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @HoangHuynh The link you have provided stays for WP8.1 Silverlight not Runtime, the OP is asking for.

Comment: Claus, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EasClientDeviceInformation class

e.g.

```
var deviceInfo = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
var manufacturer = deviceInfo.SystemManufacturer;
var name = deviceInfo.SystemProductName;
var firmwareVersion = deviceInfo.SystemFirmwareVersion;
var osVersion = "8.1"; // Only 8.1 so far. No os version method exists afaik in 8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Universal/WinRT apps only work in wp 8.1, so the OS version can only be 8.1. When they make wp8.2 or wp9, they'll probably add a way to check what OS version is installed...

If you're looking for the firmware version, you can get it with:

```
Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation deviceInfo = new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation();
var firmwareVersion = deviceInfo.SystemFirmwareVersion;
```

Comment: So from your answer, are there ways in which he might access the information he was asking about?